# I’m using Raspberry Pi 3B and having an error for running tflite

Tags: python, webcam

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/tflite1/TFLite_detection_webcam.py", line 122, in <module>
    with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/tflite1/My_Model/labelmap.txt'
```

Comment: what's  your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post